# How can I make my selected tab change color?

Tags: html, css

I've created a tab menu using Divs and CSS, and I'm wondering how I can make the selected tab change color? I assumed it would be by making .tab's background color different, but for some reason it only works for half of the tab... See here: http://www.sunporchhomes.com/features-3

Does anyone know why that is? See code below.

**Features.html**

```
<div class="tabcontent">
<div class="left_lane float">
<div class="tab blu" id="t1">INTERIORS</div><br>
<div class="tab" id="t2">BATHROOMS</div><br>
<div class="tab" id="t3">KITCHEN</div><br>
<div class="tab" id="t4">EXTRAS</div><br>
</div>
```

**.CSS**

```
.tabcontent {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top:35px;
  padding-left:485px;
  width: 600px; !important /*HOLD TABS AND CONTENT*/
  z-index:205;
  height:300px;

}
.left_lane {
  border-right: 2px #ffffff solid; 
  padding-right: 0px;
  width:100px;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  color:#ffffff;
  background-color:#6cc7df;
  height:176px;
  font-size:14px;

}
.right {

  background-color:#0ba8cb;
  width:410;
  height:500;
}
.float {
  float: left;
  padding-left:0px;
padding-top:10px;
}

.tab { 
  height:20px;
  padding-left:8px;
  border-bottom: 2px #FFF solid;

}

.tab #active {

}



.cnt {
  display: none;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#ffffff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right:10px;
}
#c1 {
  display: block;

}
.clear {
  clear: left;
}
.blu {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color:#0ba8cb;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the tabs divs are only 20px, which is what gets filled with that darker blue. The lighter blue appears to be coming from another element rendering behind that winds up showing when the front div changes color, probably b/c of padding or margin settings.

For example, the padding of the container element is affecting the first tab, as it's being pushed down by the padding-top of the parent div.

I suggest using Chrome devtools or FireFox/IE devtools to hover over your html elements and look at what styles are affecting them, and what the actual geometries of their boxes are. Makes debugging this stuff much easier.

Comment: Yep. i looked at it in console, and the padding and aligments are all helter skelter.

Comment: I figured this was the case, but even when I change the height of the tab from e.g. 20px to 40px, I still get that extra space/padding. Guess I'll have to play around :) Thank you!

Comment: The height isn't the problem, it's the padding and margin.  I was just saying that the colored part was exactly the height of the specified element.

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with CSS's:

```
padding-top
margin-top
```

for the `tab` and `left_lane` classes.

I got some almost-satisfactory results, but I am not a fan of hard-coding pixel dimensions. So I'll leave it up to you.

Answer (score -1):

Add an "active" class to the "li" as given bellow. Also add an simple css. The css code also added bellow.

HTML code

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://sunporchhomes.com">HOME</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="/features-3" id="current">FEATURES</a></li>
  <li><a href="/floor-plan-2">FLOORPLAN</a> </li>
  <li><a href="/neighbourhood-3">NEIGHBOURHOOD</a></li>
  <li><a href="/warranty">WARRANTY</a></li>
  <li><a href="/faq-2">ROWHOME FAQ</a> </li>
  <li><a href="/about">ABOUT US</a></li>
```

CSS code,

`ul li.active { bacground: #ff0000; }`